# Coauthoring with a reviewer possible?

Tags: peer-review, etiquette, writing

I recently submitted an article to a math journal and got a response
from a reviewer, with an attachment. In it, I have found some good 
advice that could improve my article tremendously.

I am a bit suspicious of its accuracy since it could resolve
what I have been working with for some months in a few 
sentences.

But anyway, it was enough for me to ask the reviewer for
coauthoring with me.

My question would be, does it often happen that
an author asks a referee for coauthoring during
the review process? Or could it even be possible?

I was given a month to revise my article, but
the chance that I could revise successfully
by myself seems to be fat.

I would be looking forward to any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot really give you much advice, as we don't know the details. You should contact the managing editor at the journal (or, if you don't know who that is, just contact any editor of the journal). Describe your situation. The editor can talk with the reviewer while maintaining initial anonymity. Good luck. --- I'm closing this question as it's not actually about mathematics.

Comment: Related question: [How to offer a reviewer to be co-author?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13765/how-to-offer-a-reviewer-to-be-co-author)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, it is possible.**

If you want to invite the reviewer to be a coauthor, send a request through the editor.  If the editor agrees, they will forward your invitation to the reviewer.  If the reviewer accepts, they will reply to the editor, who will introduce the reviewer to you, and off you go.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this kind of questions cannot be absolute or definitive. All depends on details (how much did the referee improve your proof, does it make sense to ignore the proof of referee, etc).

I've not direct experience but I have a friend to which this arrived at least three times in the last years. At each time it was the occasion to start a new and fruitful collaboration.

So I see this in the positive.

Hope this can help...

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question directly I'm afraid, as I'm just not 100% on how the process would work in this situation.

But for sure, a new reviewer would need to be found for the revised manuscript. Potentially, you might need to withdraw the submission and start from fresh. It's a unique situation and I'm sure the editor would be understanding.

(My experience is in engineering journals, however I imagine the 'no conflict of interest' requirement between authors and reviewers would be applicable here too.)